# Post from react-native

Tags: json, react-native

I'm trying to post from a `react-native` app, but it displays this error: `JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`

Here is my code :

```
    fetch ('http://url.com/register.php',{
           method: 'POST',
           header: {
           Accept :'application/json',
           'Content-type':'application/json',
           },
           body: JSON.stringify({
           email: userEmail,
           }),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>{
              alert(responseJson);
         })
    .catch((error)=>{
           alert(error);
     });
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response which is being `JSON.parse()`d by `response.json()` is not valid JSON. Apparently it contains a `<` as the error says.

Answer (score 1):

Look into chrome developer console end check what is send to and from PHP.

Comment: how can i look into if the data is from an app?

Comment: This should help https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

Comment: in the console appears `dataSent: null`

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex error my app was sending correctly the info but my `register.php` didn't recieve the info because `mod_security` was enabled so the response was:

`<script>document.cookie = “humans_21909=1”; document.location.reload(true)</script>`

That's why the error says `JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`